# Inserting values to a column within a range of big integers in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to fill a column's values with some numbers between a specific range.

My column's data type is bigint. Not array of bigint.

I am trying to use code at below;

```
INSERT INTO public.usertransactions (bank_order_code) VALUES 
  ( (SELECT array_agg(g.i) :: bigint
     FROM generate_series(8000,8069) as g(i)));
```

After this i am getting this error :

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type integer[] to bigint
LINE 2: ( (SELECT array_agg(g.i) :: bigint
                                 ^
SQL state: 42846
Character: 88
```

How can i fix it.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want an array of `bigint`.  To convert to an array, you need `[]`:

```
SELECT array_agg(g.i)::bigint[]
FROM generate_series(8000, 8069) as g(i);
```

Note:  I wouldn't recommend `VALUES` in this case:

```
INSERT INTO public.usertransactions (bank_order_code)
    SELECT array_agg(g.i)::bigint[]
    FROM generate_series(8000, 8069) as g(i);
```

If you want to insert 70 rows, then why are you using arrays?  Just use:

```
INSERT INTO public.usertransactions (bank_order_code)
    SELECT i
    FROM generate_series(8000, 8069) as g(i);
```

Comment: My data type is just bigint. Not bigint[]. My bad. Added it to question.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert the result of `array_agg`, which is an array, into an integer column.

So, since you do not have a `bigint` array in your table, one must assume you just want to create 70 records between 8000 and 8069 and therefore do not need `array_agg`, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO usertransactions (bank_order_code) 
VALUES (generate_series(8000,8069));
```

In case you wanted to achieve a sum of all generated values just use the function `sum()` as follows

```
INSERT INTO usertransactions (bank_order_code) 
SELECT sum(i) FROM generate_series(8000,8069) AS g(i);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=17cf1ccf25d9df501af8e32b8269f91d)